# Flutter - IOS Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I am getting this error while trying to create an IPA in my flutter project how can I solve it please help

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[37847]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1ebbdf130) and
/Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1067c42c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[37847]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x1ebbdf180) and
/Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1067c4318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/6r/5vp_qlmd5lqcy6q5wtp8yg8w0000gn/T/flutter_tools.iZLmcz/flutter_ios_build_temp_diryOLwq7/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained
protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                   ^~~~~
                                                   AnyObject
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained
protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                 ^~~~~
                                                 AnyObject
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained
protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                   ^~~~~
                                                   AnyObject
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained
protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                 ^~~~~
                                                 AnyObject
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:321:30: warning: conditional downcast from 'Error?' to 'NSError' is a
bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        shouldRetry = (error as? NSError)?.code == URLError.notConnectedToInternet.rawValue
                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StorageDeleteTask.swift:74:46: warning: conditional downcast from 'Error?' to
'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        self?.fetcherCompletion?(data, error as? NSError)
                                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageDownloadTask.swift:179:45: warning: conditional downcast from 'Error?' to
'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        self.fetcherCompletion?(data, error as? NSError)
                                      ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                                            as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StorageGetDownloadURLTask.swift:91:46: warning: conditional downcast from
'Error?' to 'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        self?.fetcherCompletion?(data, error as? NSError)
                                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StorageGetMetadataTask.swift:87:46: warning: conditional downcast from
'Error?' to 'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        self?.fetcherCompletion?(data, error as? NSError)
                                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StorageListTask.swift:134:46: warning: conditional downcast from 'Error?' to
'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        self?.fetcherCompletion?(data, error as? NSError)
                                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StoragePath.swift:165:28: warning: conditional downcast from 'String?' to
'NSString' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
    if let object = object as? NSString {
                    ~~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~~
                           as          ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/StorageReference.swift:52:25: warning: conditional downcast from 'String?' to
'NSString' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
    return (path.object as? NSString)?.lastPathComponent ?? ""
            ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~~
                        as          ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StorageTokenAuthorizer.swift:44:30: warning: conditional downcast from
'Error?' to 'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        if let error = error as? NSError {
                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Internal/StorageUpdateMetadataTask.swift:97:46: warning: conditional downcast from
'Error?' to 'NSError' is a bridging conversion; did you mean to use 'as'?
        self?.fetcherCompletion?(data, error as? NSError)
                                       ~~~~~ ^~~ ~~~~~~~
                                             as         ?
/Users/macbookair/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-5.2.10/ios/Classes/FileUtils.m:133:30: warning: unused variable 'exportError' [-Wunused-variable]
                    NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                             ^
1 warning generated.
/Users/macbookair/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-5.2.10/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:357:1: warning: implementing deprecated method
[-Wdeprecated-implementations]
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url{
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/file_picker/file_picker-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDocumentPickerViewController.h:27
:1: note: method 'documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:' declared here
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("documentPicker:didPickDocumentsAtURLs:", ios(8.0,
11.0));
^
1 warning generated.
error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileC
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Rele
ase-iphoneos/firebase_core.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o
/Users/macbookair/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.8.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileC
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Rele
ase-iphoneos/firebase_auth.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.o
/Users/macbookair/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.3.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
/Users/macbookair/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-4.4.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:490:29: warning: comparison of distinct pointer
types ('FIRQuery *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull') [-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
  if (query == nil || query == [NSNull null]) {
                      ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
2023-05-04 23:20:18.339 ibtoold[48887:193551] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
    TMPDIR = "/var/folders/6r/5vp_qlmd5lqcy6q5wtp8yg8w0000gn/T/00617C69-878C-4FEF-8577-8BA55884BE7C";
}
/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][watch][][appLauncher][41mm][2x][][][][2d][102.png]: warning: The app icon set
"AppIcon" has an unassigned child.
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][watch][][appLauncher][41mm][2x][][][][2d][102.png]: warning: The app icon set
"AppIcon" has an unassigned child.
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][iphone][57x57][][][1x][][][]: notice: 57x57 app icons only apply to iPhone apps
targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][iphone][57x57][][][2x][][][]: notice: 57x57@2x app icons only apply to iPhone apps
targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][50x50][][][1x][][][]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad
apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][50x50][][][2x][][][]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad
apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][72x72][][][1x][][][]: notice: 72x72 app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting
releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][72x72][][][2x][][][]: notice: 72x72@2x app icons only apply to iPad apps
targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps
targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applicat
ions/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applicat
ions/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applicat
ions/Runner.app/Assets.car
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Re
lease-iphoneos/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileAssetCatalog
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applicat
ions/Runner.app /Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
mkdir -p
/Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fvcdyistcwhfskekwbwatbwpqvmq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.
app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
/Users/macbookair/projeler/komiserlikvemisyonkoruma/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/6r/5vp_qlmd5lqcy6q5wtp8yg8w0000gn/T/flutter_tools.iZLmcz/flutter_ios_build_temp_diryOLwq7/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Encountered error while archiving for device.